# Font-size and img height too big at website through smartphone OnePlus 3T

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, height, font-size

I've just launched my website's mobile version for browsers, which looks as expected in all the devices I tried, including many different sizes through the Device Emulator of Chrome DevTools.

However, a user just reported that he is seeing both images and text far too big with his OnePlus 3T smartphone.

Expected smartphone layout:

[image: Expected smartphone layout]

Layout with OnePlus 3T:

[image: Layout with OnePlus 3T 1]

[image: Layout with OnePlus 3T 2]

I tried to reproduce it in Chrome's Device Emulator, but without success.
I am using px as units in the CSS for `font-size` and `height`.

OnePlus 3T's screen has the following specs, which I think are quite normal:

> Size  5.5 inches, 83.4 cm2 (~73.1% screen-to-body ratio)
>
> Resolution    1080 x 1920 pixels, 16:9 ratio (~401 ppi density)

Any idea of why everything is appearing so big?

[Here](http://www.travelinho.com/en/results/?Orig=Heidelberg&Dest=Mallorca&OutboundDate=25-05-2018) a link to one of such layouts, in case anybody wants to have a look at it.

### Update

Apparently, the problem is related to the meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Somehow that Smartphone is applying the meta tag, or something that creates the same effect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the following line in the header, the problem was solved:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1200, user-scalable=no">
```

Answer (score 1):

Might sound obvious but has he changed the font size or Display size under Android Settings > Display?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. I will ask him.

Comment: The user says that nothing in the settings was changed

Answer (score 1):

I would use relative measurements like **em** or **rem** instead of **px**. You can scale down the page by reducing the fontsize on smaller devices.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.icon-selector {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
}}
```